# ¿Como encontrar todos los objetos que implementen ICollection?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Dada esta propiedad:

```
Public Overridable Property Collecions As ICollection(Of String)
```

La cual podríamos instanciar así:

```
variable.Collecions = New List(Of String)
```

O así:

```
variable.Collecions = New LinkedList(Of String)
```

Me surge la siguiente pregunta:
¿No hay alguna forma fácil de encontrar todos los tipos que implementen `ICollection`, y que por lo tanto puedan ser instanciados? 
Esperaba encontrarlos a través del examinador de objetos, pero no he visto cómo. Mis búsquedas en google tampoco han arrojado demasiada luz.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Si la pongo en c# la respuesta, se vale?

Comment: Sí Einer. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que buscar todos los tipos implementan la interfaz con el metodo [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) que verifica si la instancia puede ser asignada al `System.Type` pasado por parametro:

```
public ICollection<T> GetAllICollectionTTypes<T>()
{
 var collectionType = typeof(ICollection<T>);
 var collections = typeof(ICollection<T>);
            var collections = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(x => collectionType.IsAssignableFrom(x))
                 .Select(x=> Activator.CreateInstance<ICollection<T>>(x))
                .ToList();

return collections
}
```

El metodo `Activator.CreateInstance<ICollection<T>>` crea una nueva instancia del tipo encontrado.

Uso:

```
ICollection<string> instanciasQueImplementanICollectionString = GetAllICollectionTTypes<String>();
```